# DbContext crashes with PrimitiveType != null error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework Code First, the web application crashes on a call to DbContext with the following error:

> Assertion failed
>
> Expression: primitiveType != null
>
> Description: Assertion failed: primitiveType != null

It crashes on the following line of code:

```
public class MyDb : DbContext {
```

which is called by:

```
MyDb _db = new MyDb();
```

So it seams like calling DbContext generates a fatal error. DbContext is an EF function and I cannot debug inside EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Check the line of code where it fails, an assertion can't fail on the class definition.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue? I just installed VS2012 and now one of my sites is having the same problem.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?
I'm having the same issue.

Thanks, Koen

Comment: nope sorry. it was project I temporarily jumped in. But I check out the code tomorrow to see if it's fixed (and what fixed it)

Comment: Sorry, not fixed yet. But it's a problem related to my PC, because it works on an other developer's PC and in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem related to older versions of EntityFramework. It happens sometimes when copying a Visual Studio Project to a different machine. This can cause the application to calculate a different ModelHash  than the one that is in the database (inside the EdmMetaData table). Solution is to delete the EdmMetaData table and use `DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MyContext>( new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());` to put it back in place, or even better: Upgrade to a newer version of EntityFramework that is not utilizing the EdmMetaData table and ModelHashes.

Answer (score 1):

After installing asp.net4.5 I have same error.
The Answer for me is to update Entity Framework to new version.

Deleting "EdmMetaData" table didn't resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I swicth to linq to sql and dint get this error. Dont know what entities is doing to cause this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your EntityFramework version