# WebDev.WebServer40.exe - Assertion failed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I've just taken over 2 MVC Projects, and I haven't worked on MVC much before. It's supposed to be MVC3, and for both projects, when I try to run, I get the following error:

"WebDev.WebServer40.exe - Assertion failed.

Expression: primtiveType != null
Description: Assertion failed: primitiveType != null"

I know both projects compile and work, as I've seen someone else run them. But they're not here any longer.

Is there a specific setting or reference that I'm missing? 
I just run like a "normal/traditional" solution right??

Help please?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio (guessing 2010)? Are you opening with a .SLN file?

Comment: @Belogix, 

I'm using Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel, and yes, I'm using a .SLN file. On the .csproj file, the Guids are:

<ProjectTypeGuids>
{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Comment: Do the projects use Entity Framework. If so, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430223/dbcontext-crashes-with-primitivetype-null-error or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516420/error-iisexpress-exe-assertion-failed

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bad install of VS 2010.

Thanks for all the help everyone!